# Javascript :: Audio source is null

Tags: javascript, audio

I want to access this tag with javascript and play the audio with no controls:

```
 <audio id="audio" src=""></audio>
```

this is the function:

```
 function play_song(){

      var id = Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect(input); //this returns a valid input

      var audio = document.getElementById('audio'); 

      audio.src = 'audio' + '/' + id + '.wav'; 

      audio.play();
     }
```

On `console.log` I get `audio.src = null`;

where is the bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On `console.log` I get `audio.src = null;`
>
> where is the bug?

Add `src` attribute to element at `html`

```
<audio id="audio" src=""></audio>
```

Comment: thanks, but I I still get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null`

Comment: @data_garden _"thanks, but I I still get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of null"_ Can you create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? , include text of  `Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect` at Question ? Does `Song.prototype.lyricsIntersect(input)` return results asynchronously ?  Is `input` defined ? How is `play_song` called ?

Comment: tried `audio.load()`, to no avail. `function` works when `<audio>`is preloaded on `html` page (`preload="auto"`) , but I have many many audio files, and would like to load them dynamically..yes, `input is defined`. `play_ song` is called at `onclick="play_song( );`

Comment: @data_garden Have you checked `console` at https://jsfiddle.net/patalanov/9e1xy4g7/ ? Five of the libraries that you have attempted to load responded with `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
(index):310 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Comment: @data_garden Note also that `"/audio"` is not a local path at jsfiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107089/discussion-between-guest271314-and-data-garden).